# Eclipse PHP file not able to see html file in same project folder

Tags: php, html

I'm using the Include func in a index.php file that looks for a header.html file and getting the following 2 errors:

> Warning: include(includes/header.html): failed to open stream: No such
>   file or directory in C:\wamp\www\Projects\Chapter Three\index.php on
>   line 3

&

> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'includes/header.html' for
>   inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in
>   C:\wamp\www\Projects\Chapter Three\index.php on line 3

I verified both **index.php** & **header.html** are in the same dir via Explorer so what else should I check? Thanx!

Comment: They're not in the same directory in your code - it's looking for `header.html` in a subdirectory called `includes/`

Comment: try `includes\header.html` sometimes windows mess things like that :S

Comment: This is what the line currently looks like ...                   include ('includes/header.html');  How do you verify (which I thought I've already done) the dir for all files in Eclipse (Zend)?

Comment: You were correct, I removed the subdir altogether and it works! Thanks.  I'm feeling pretty foolish.

Answer (score 0):

You need quotes around the include URL, like `include 'home.html';`, If that doesnt work, try throwing a / before the url, `include '/home.html';`

Comment: This is what the code looks like ...<?php # - index.php
$page_title = 'Welcome to this Site!';

include ('includes/header.html');
?>

<h1>Content Header</h1>

 <p>This is.....</p>
<?php
include ('includes/footer.html');
?>

Comment: Try just using `'header.html'` instead of `'includes/header.html'`, if they are in the same directory.